# porque cuando ingreso una fila nueva en el datagridview se sobreescribe en la primera fila vb.net

Tags: vb.net

estoy haciendo un sistema de punto de venta con lector de codigo de barras, los datos los cargo a un datagridview si agrego articulos con el mismo codigo de barras en la columna "cantidad" los suma automaticamente, pero al leer otro articulo con diferente codigo de barras en la primera lectura si lo agrega en una fila nueva, pero al agregar otr articulo igual, lo reescribe en la primera fila del datagridview, podrian ayudarme agrego parte del codigo para mayor explicacion

```
Dim fila As Integer = 0
Dim i As Integer
Dim cantidad As Integer = 0
Dim existe As Boolean = False





Private Sub txt_No_Factura_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt_No_Factura.KeyPress
    Dim codigo As String

    If txt_No_Factura.Text <> "" Then
        Try

            If (e.KeyChar = (Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))) Then
                Dim conexion As SqlConnection
                conexion = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Gabriel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ventas;Integrated Security=True")
                conexion.Open()
                Dim cod As String = txt_No_Factura.Text
                Dim cadena As String = "select codigo_barra,idproducto,nombre,precio_venta from producto where codigo_barra ='" & cod & "'"
                Dim comando As SqlCommand
                comando = New SqlCommand(cadena, conexion)
                Dim registro As SqlDataReader
                registro = comando.ExecuteReader()
                registro.Read()


                cod_barra.Text = registro(0)
                txt_idproducto.Text = registro(1)
                txt_nombreProducto.Text = registro(2)
                txt_precioUnitario.Text = registro(3)

                datalistado.ColumnCount = 5
                With datalistado
                    .Columns(0).Name = "Cantidad"
                    .Columns(1).Name = "Codigo Barra"
                    .Columns(2).Name = "Codigo Producto"
                    .Columns(3).Name = "Nombre"
                    .Columns(4).Name = "Precio de Venta"
                End With
                conexion.Close()

                If datalistado.Rows.Count = Nothing Then
                    cantidad += 1
                    datalistado.Rows.Add()
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(0).Value = cantidad.ToString() - 1
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(2).Value = txt_idproducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(3).Value = txt_nombreProducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(f).Cells(4).Value = txt_precioUnitario.Text
                    'f = f + 1
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = ""
                End If

                If datalistado.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    For fila As Integer = 0 To datalistado.Rows.Count - 1
                        If datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text Then 'cod.toString()
                            existe = True
                        Else
                            existe = False
                        End If

                    Next

                End If

                If existe = True Then
                    'f = f + 1
                    cantidad += 1
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(0).Value = (cantidad.ToString() - 1)
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(1).Value = cod_barra.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(3).Value = txt_nombreProducto.Text
                    datalistado.Rows(fila).Cells(4).Value = txt_precioUnitario.Text
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = "" ' agregue esto
                    'f = f + 1
                End If
                If existe = False Then
                    datalistado.Rows.Add(txt_cantiad.Text, cod_barra.Text, txt_idproducto.Text, txt_nombreProducto.Text, txt_precioUnitario.Text)
                    'f = f + 1
                    txt_No_Factura.Text = ""
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("El articulo no fue registrado cuando ingreso a almacen")
        End Try


    End If 'fin del if para validar que no este vacia el textox

End Sub
```

Comment: El sitio no funciona copiando tu pregunta una y otra vez. Te deje comentarios en la otra publicacion que ni contestaste. Encontes?

Comment: ok, disculpa por mi ignorancia, no encontre una forma para editar mi problema con mi codigo, por lo que volvi hacer de nuevo mi consulta, soy nuevo en el foro, y gracias por las observaciones

Comment: Para editar, hay un boton editar debajo de tu publicacion. de esa forma puedes modificar todo lo necesario. Tu otra pregunta tiene hasta una respuesta. Si sirve aceptala, si no sirve, aclara porque no sirve.

Comment: Y no hay porque disculparse, todos siempre estamos aprendiendo. Pero lee lo que te pedimos que leas, como el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Asi evitas futuros problemas...